# Ack for files with two phrases on Windows

Tags: grep, ack

I want to Ack for files that contain both "foo" AND "bar". I found lots of answers for how to do this on Linux, but not on Windows.

Comment: Also why doesn't Ack offer an option to do this without any shell hacks? They offer so many seemingly useless flags.

Comment: _ack_ is written in Perl5, so the documentation is the same. See https://beyondgrep.com/documentation/ .  It's customary here for folks asking for help to provide samples of their scripts, and the resulting error messages, if the scripts fail. Please do so by clicking [edit] and expanding on your question, so everyone can see all the information about your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The way you've probably seen is:

```
ack bar $(ack -l foo)
```

but that relies on shell specifics that I'm guessing Windows doesn't allow.  Here's another way you can do it which should work in Windows.

```
ack -l foo | ack -x bar
```

The `-x` option says "use the file list from standard input as the list of files to search".

> why doesn't Ack offer an option to do this without any shell hacks?

Because nobody's written it.

If you think it should be a feature, then the way to move that forward is by following the instructions in the manual:

```
   Please report any bugs or feature requests to the issues list at
   Github: https://github.com/beyondgrep/ack2/issues
```

> They offer so many seemingly useless flags.

I suggest that what you are calling "useless flags" are "options that I have not figured out the use for yet".